# Localize dateinterval in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I've a entity method returning a PHP `DateInterval` between a `DateTime` property of this entity and now, to know how many time left before this datetime.

I want to display this interval in Twig so I used something like that:

```
{{ myEntity.getTimeRemaining | date("%D days %H Hours %i Mins ") }}
```

It's working fine.

Now, how can I localize this format? (and eventually consider the plural)
I've found `transchoice` method but it's seem to be only to localize date, not a interval.

Comment: Good question. Can you be more specific about 'localised'? Do you just mean translated to the relevant locale, or is there something else?

Comment: Yes, I just want a string translate. So for example "%D jours %H Heures %i Minutes " is user local is french.  I would like to display the correct plural too, but this would be a bonus :)

Comment: I think you'd need a custom Twig filter which receives the translator as an argument, gets the translation for each of the necessary terms, and then does the concatenation manually (say, with a `sprintf()`).

Comment: take a look at [KnpTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle) that can do all for you

Comment: Ok, that not exactly answer my question, but this bundle is exactly what I needed. I will use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [KnpTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle)

I think this bundle can simplify your implementation, so you can directly dump the time difference between now without pass thru a DateInterval, you can simply with the current date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(myEntity.getMyTimeField) }}
```

This compare with the another date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(myEntity.getMyTimeField , to ) }}
```

The translation is enabled by default, simply review the translations files or add as you need.

Hope this help